# Rails - ActiveAdmin create relationship count column sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, columnsorting

I am working on ActiveAdmin and I am trying to display a column name `Active Jobs` with a count

There are three models involved in getting this count

```
 1. Staffroom 
 2. StaffroomPage
 3. Job



class StaffroomPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staffroom

class Staffroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :staffroom_page
  has_many :jobs

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staffroom
```

Now inside the `admin/staffroom_pages.rb` I am able to display the column and the count

```
column :active_jobs, sortable: 'active_jobs' do |staffroom_page|
  staffroom_page.staffroom.jobs.where(:state=> 'active').count
end
```

However I am not able to sort the data via `active_jobs` and I see the following error

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "active_jobs" does not exist

So the question is how to make the sort to work for column `active_jobs`, please note that this is not the only sortable column on page, almost all columns are sortable and this is the only one not working.

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3085) on the activeadmin github a possible workaround to this problem would be

```
index do
  column :active_jobs, sortable: 'active_jobs' do |staffroom_page|
    staffroom_page.staffroom.jobs.where(:state=> 'active').count
  end
end

controller do


def scoped_collection
  super.joins(
    %(LEFT JOIN "jobs" ON "staffroom_pages"."staffroom_id" = "jobs"."staffroom_id"
        AND "jobs"."state" = 'active'))
      .select('staffroom_pages.*, COUNT(jobs.id) as active_jobs')
      .group('staffroom_pages.id')
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for having a look, this leads to the error PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "jobs"
LINE 1: ...staffrooms" ON "staffroom_pages"."staffroom_id" = "jobs"."st...

Comment: my bad, I had originally thought to join through the staffroom table, but then I realized since both tables have the same foreign key you could skip that join, but I forgot to change what table I was joining to.  Edited

Comment: now it seems to complain about PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "active" does not exist LINE 2: AND "jobs"."state" = "active" WHERE "staffroom_pages...

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at the documentation on [custom sorting](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html)?